# Getting a new JSON object when clicking a button (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, quote

I'm brand new to webdev, I'm trying to build a web app that gets a new quote whenever the button `#getQuote` is clicked.

This is my my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // function get_new will get a new JSON object     
    function get_new() {
        $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
            var quote = a[0].content.slice(3, -6);
            var author = '- ' + a[0].title;

            var my_quote = $('<i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> ' + quote + ' <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>');

            $('.quoteBody').html(my_quote);
            $('.quoteAuthor').html(author);

            // tweet the quote 
            $("#tweet").click(function() {
                $(this).attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + '"' + quote + '" - ' + author).attr("target", "_blank");
            });
        });
    }

    // calling function to appear as default
    get_new();
    // when clicked, get new quote 
    $('#getQuote').click(function() {
        get_new();
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated guys.

Here's the codepen for anyone interested:
https://codepen.io/tadm123/pen/YNvdyr

Comment: Well what's wrong with your code? At the first glance, it looks ok!

Comment: It just doesn't get a new quote, I updated and posted the codepen

Comment: With the developer console in Chrome open, it works fine.  Close the console, it stops working for me...

Comment: jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] ) . getJSON accepts a 3rd argument which is a success function use it to retrieve error message.

Comment: I've got the same issue as @chris, weird

Comment: I think your code is working just fine. I think codepen always show the same quote because it's a development tool it doen't need to waste the developper time downloading new JSON object everytime he type a letter in the code! Try your code somewhere else and it will work!

Comment: I did what @Sergio Alen suggested and it works now, thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed, it's just a cache issue on codepen.

Add this line to your code to set cache false:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Be careful using this in a live environment, you dont want to affect all your ajax requests with cache:false. So I'd recommend you using a normal jQuery ajax call and set the property cache to false specifically to this function only:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/path/to/file.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: or you put url as below to avoid cache in get Request

$.get(url,{ "_": $.now() }, function(data){
  console.log(data);
});

Comment: Strange, I added the `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); in codepen and it didn't like it, I actually had to change the URL itself in the CP environment for it to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is 100% right. It just so happens that the browser is caching the result of the url you're accessing. I noticed that Codepen was caching the result and my browser was caching it too when I tested it with files on my computer. So after it hits that URL the first time, it thinks something along the lines of "Oh, I've already gone to this URL and I already know what the result is. So to save time, I'll just give it the same data as before."

To combat this (this might be considered hacky?), add the current time to the end of the URL (because the time will always be different) like so:

```
function get_new(){
    var currentDate = new Date().getTime(); // create new date
    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&date=" + currentDate, function(a) {  // add it to end of URL
        var quote = a[0].content.slice(3,-6);
        var author = '- ' + a[0].title;
        var my_quote = $('<i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> ' + quote + ' <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>');

        $('.quoteBody').html(my_quote);
        $('.quoteAuthor').html(author);

        // tweet the quote
        $("#tweet").click(function(){
          $(this).attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+ '"'+ quote + '" - ' + author).attr("target","_blank");
        });
    });
}
```

Also sometimes the result will come slowly, but I think that's because of the speed of the server your requesting the quotes from. Another challenge can be to have a loader show while it's getting a quote from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Put cache false in your URL. This is because you are getting same data again and again

```
https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&cache=false&callback
```

Answer (score 0):

Close... to get it to work with the console closed, the `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` didn't work.  However, randomizing the URL did:

```
$.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=&cache="+Math.random(), function(a) {
```